# TemplateDoesNotExist on doing String concatenation in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

My template tag:

```
{% with "http://example.com/verify-email/"|add:key as verify_url %}
{% include verify_url %}
{% endwith %}
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: http://example.com/verify-email/zq5hdh7dqlaof4nrkc9e4gsreyblbmol2ax5m6wnmsexcl6p6khjzflixd2nkr2l
```

Location of this file: project-name/templates/account/email/

settings.py contains:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: you cannot include a url as a dropin. You have to load it via iframe

Comment: What's your URLs.py look like?

Comment: Have you configured your urls.py to direct the url to the corresponding view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% include ... %}` excepts a template, not a URL.

You can do something like this:

```
{% include account/email/the-email.html with key=key %}
```

Obviously replace `key` with whatever vars the template requires.